# Javascript A thank you page with user name on it

Tags: javascript

I have a form where a user input name and other contact information. I validate the input and then redirect to a thank you page. I wanted to personalize the page by having the user name appear as part of the thank you note. I tried document.getElementById(Name1).value to retrieve the value of the Name but it it is giving Undefined.
Is there a way for me to set the value of the Name1 field to another variable that I call again to include it in my text message?

Comment: Show us the code. When you redirect it you can send the user name as part of the URL (as a hash maybe) and get it in the thanks page with `window.location.hash`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `undefined` because in the thank-you page, you don't have the form anymore.. the best way to do it is on the server side.

If you insist on doing it completely on the client side, then you might need some hack. One idea is to use `window.location.hash` as @MateiMihai mentioned. Another idea is to use local storage which saves values on the client side. This can be helpful: http://www.jstorage.info/